# How to not lose color when pipe output to variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pipe

How to not lose color when pipe output to variable?

Let's say i have some directory with some file:

```
SOME_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
touch "$SOME_DIR/abc"
```

When i do ls and grep there the "ab" in the output is colored by grep

```
ls "$SOME_DIR" | grep ab
abc # 'ab' is red
```

But if i pip the output to a variable and echo it, the color is gone

```
LS_OUTPUT=`ls "$SOME_DIR" | grep ab`
echo "$LS_OUTPUT"
abc # no colors
```

I also tried

```
LS_OUTPUT=$((ls "$SOME_DIR" | grep ab) 2>&1)
echo "$LS_OUTPUT"
abc # no colors
```

and

```
LS_OUTPUT=$(ls "$SOME_DIR" | grep ab)
echo "$LS_OUTPUT"
abc # no colors
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Your version of `grep` is detecting whether its output is a terminal or not, and adjusting its use of color accordingly. Check `grep`'s documentation for an option to always use color.

Comment: First you have to understand where the color comes from and where it goes.

Comment: There will be some escape sequences around that variable if you really manage to preserve them.

Comment: Thank's for duplication detection. Didn't found this before. Adding --color=always to the grep solve this issue